# Simple Jpa query not working

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to delete the oldest created item which belongs to an user:

This is what I have tried:

```
    em.createQuery("delete from items i where i.user =:user and i.createdOn =(select min(i1.createdOn) from items i1)")
          .setParameter("user", user)
          .executeUpdat();
```

And i have also tried :

```
    Query query =
            em.createQuery("select i.id from item i where i.user =:user and i.createdOn =(select min(i1.createdOn) from items i1)")
                    .setParameter("user", user);
    Integer item_id = query.getFirstResult();

    em.createQuery("delete from items i where i.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", item_id)
            .executeUpdate();
```

the above seems to always return 0 at the first query and thus doesn't work.

Comment: Set `hibernate.show_sql=true` in persistence.xml and after that see what it actually fires in native query or execute it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your model correctly, you want to delete the item of a user that he created first. But you are trying to delete an item of a specific user which was created first by *any* user.

The query your need:

```
delete from items i 
  where i.user = :user and i.createdOn =
    (select min(i1.createdOn) from items i1 where i1.user = :user)
```